# I would like explanation of the behaviour of Perl's regular expression engine

Tags: regex, perl

#### Update by @Borodin

I've rewritten this code as something I think is more comprehensible. The OP was comparing `b` with `d` and suchlike, and I've changed all the symbols to more distinct ASCII characters. The result is equivalent to that of the OP's original code

I've briefly checked manually all of the regex patterns, but I don't see a discrepancy

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings qw/ all FATAL /;

use List::Util 'max';

my @tests = (
    [ vvOHvXcvv => qr/ ^ ( (v*) O    | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ /x ],
    [ vvOvXcvv  => qr/ ^ ( (v*) O    | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ /x ],
    [ vvXHvXcvv => qr/ ^ ( (v*) X    | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ /x ],
    [ vvXvXcvv  => qr/ ^ ( (v*) X    | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ /x ],
    [ vvOHvXcvv => qr/ ^ ( (v*) [XO] | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ /x ],
    [ vvOvXcvv  => qr/ ^ ( (v*) [XO] | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ /x ],
    [ vvXHvXcvv => qr/ ^ ( (v*) [XO] | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ /x ],
    [ vvXvXcvv  => qr/ ^ ( (v*) [XO] | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ /x ],
);

my $w1 = max map length $_->[0], @tests;
my ($no, $yes) = ( 'MATCHES', "doesn't match" );
my $w2 = max map length, $no, $yes;

for my $test ( @tests ) {
    my ( $str, $re ) = @$test;

    printf "%-*s %-*s %s\n",
            $w1+2, qq{"$str"},
            $w2, $str =~ $re ? 'MATCHES' : "doesn't match",
            $re;
}
```

#### output

```
"vvOHvXcvv" MATCHES       (?^x: ^ ( (v*) O    | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ )
"vvOvXcvv"  MATCHES       (?^x: ^ ( (v*) O    | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ )
"vvXHvXcvv" MATCHES       (?^x: ^ ( (v*) X    | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ )
"vvXvXcvv"  doesn't match (?^x: ^ ( (v*) X    | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ )
"vvOHvXcvv" doesn't match (?^x: ^ ( (v*) [XO] | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ )
"vvOvXcvv"  doesn't match (?^x: ^ ( (v*) [XO] | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ )
"vvXHvXcvv" doesn't match (?^x: ^ ( (v*) [XO] | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ )
"vvXvXcvv"  doesn't match (?^x: ^ ( (v*) [XO] | H? (v*) X )* c \2 $ )
```

---

The following Perl program tests a few strings against various regex patterns that use back-references. It illustrates a behaviour that I cannot understand.

The `$snum` and `$rnum` variables are used only to number the strings and patterns in the output for easier reading. The only thing worth reading is the contents of the `@test` array.

```perl
#! /usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my @test = (
    [ "aadeabcaa", qr/^((a*)d|e?(a*)b)*c\2$/ ],
    [ "aadabcaa", qr/^((a*)d|e?(a*)b)*c\2$/ ],
    [ "aabeabcaa", qr/^((a*)b|e?(a*)b)*c\2$/ ],
    [ "aababcaa", qr/^((a*)b|e?(a*)b)*c\2$/ ],
    [ "aadeabcaa", qr/^((a*)[bd]|e?(a*)b)*c\2$/ ],
    [ "aadabcaa", qr/^((a*)[bd]|e?(a*)b)*c\2$/ ],
    [ "aabeabcaa", qr/^((a*)[bd]|e?(a*)b)*c\2$/ ],
    [ "aababcaa", qr/^((a*)[bd]|e?(a*)b)*c\2$/ ],
);

my %snum;
my %rnum;
my $lsnum;
my $lrnum;

for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < scalar(@test); $i++ ) {

    my $t = $test[$i];  my $s = $t->[0];  my $r = $t->[1];

    my $snum = ($snum{$s} //= $lsnum++);
    my $rnum = ($rnum{$r} //= $lrnum++);

    my $match = ($s =~ $r);

    print "test $i: (S$snum) $s" .
        ($match?" MATCHES ":" DOES NOT match ") .
        "(R$rnum) $r\n";
}
```

#### output

```
test 0: (S0) aadeabcaa MATCHES (R0) (?^:^((a*)d|e?(a*)b)*c\2$)
test 1: (S1) aadabcaa MATCHES (R0) (?^:^((a*)d|e?(a*)b)*c\2$)
test 2: (S2) aabeabcaa MATCHES (R1) (?^:^((a*)b|e?(a*)b)*c\2$)
test 3: (S3) aababcaa DOES NOT match (R1) (?^:^((a*)b|e?(a*)b)*c\2$)
test 4: (S0) aadeabcaa DOES NOT match (R2) (?^:^((a*)[bd]|e?(a*)b)*c\2$)
test 5: (S1) aadabcaa DOES NOT match (R2) (?^:^((a*)[bd]|e?(a*)b)*c\2$)
test 6: (S2) aabeabcaa DOES NOT match (R2) (?^:^((a*)[bd]|e?(a*)b)*c\2$)
test 7: (S3) aababcaa DOES NOT match (R2) (?^:^((a*)[bd]|e?(a*)b)*c\2$)
```

Note that `egrep` (or at any rate, GNU `egrep`) thinks that every test above is a match.

I think that is the theoretically "correct" answer if regexp disjunction is interpreted as a non-deterministic choice, in the sense that there exists a choice of alternatives that will make the match succeed.

Also note that (`S2`, `S3`, `R1`) are obtained by replacing `b` for `d` everywhere in (`S0`, `S1`, `R0`), which is another reason to think that the fourth test should be a match.

Intuitively, I would also like tests 4–7 to be matches insofar as tests 0–3 are.

*I can sort of understand how one would arrive at the fourth test not matching: by trying the left branch and the right right branch in this order at each disjunction, *if backtracking does not correctly restore* the `\2` variable to its prior value, exploring the left branch of the R1 disjunction on the latter `ab` substring of S3  would clobber `\2` to `a` which would then not be backtracked to its `aa` value, causing the match to fail (whereas the same thing would not happen in any of the previous tests).*

But I have no idea whether my analysis is correct. Why the fifth test doesn't match really escapes me.

So anyway, my question is a combination of the following:

- Can someone explain Perl's regexp engine behavior on those examples in detail?
- Is this behavior intentional?  Is it documented somewhere?
- Should I file a bug?

Comment: I think kudos is due to those who can understand what you're written. `my $snum = ($snum{$s} = $snum{$s} // ($lsnum++))` isn't the clearest code I've seen on my desk today

Comment: @Borodin The double equal is the result of a number of edits before I posted.  I've rewritten it as `my $snum = ($snum{$s} //= $lsnum++)`: is that better? Otherwise, please free to suggest a clearer way to do the same thing, but again, this is really not the point of the question, and I made it clear that only the `@test` table or output is worth reading (the code is just for the benefit of those who want to check, reproduce or edit the tests).

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Do you think that *all eight* perl results are wrong? It's hard to know what you're contesting? Are both `perl` and `egrep` wrong, or both correct in your eyes? I assume that you see one of them as being wrong, otherwise there is no question!

Comment: `perl  -e 'print ("aabeabcaa" =~ qr/^((a*)b|e?(a*)b)*c\2$/);print "\n";'` gives **eabaaa** I think something in your loops

Comment: before reading this question, my understanding was that \2 would refer to the capture from the last repetition of the outer `()*`, so test 0 was a surprise to me.  It does seem that backtracking makes things unpredictable to the point where it seems like a bug; does running the cases under `perl -Mre=debug -e'"string" =~ /regex/' provide you any insight into what is actually happening

Comment: @Borodin from the question it seems like all are expected to match, and at minimum a coherent explanation of *why* they don't would be a good answer

Comment: `perl -Mre=Debug,MATCH,BUFFERS` also tells what it's doing with the capture groups. This might make it easier to decide whether this is a bug.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks for the debug options, I didn't know about them. I'll try to understand the output (which is fairly long, for each one of my test cases).

Comment: @Borodin I'm not saying Perl is wrong: my understanding of regexps-with-backreferences as a mathematical construct seems to coincide with the way `egrep` does it, i.e., all tests are matches, but I can imagine different ways of doing things (JavaScript has an answer both different from that of Perl and of `egrep`, and I think it also makes sense). Maybe there's a sensible and/or documented explanation for Perl's behavior, in which case I'm happy, but at the very least you have to admit that it's not obvious (whereas predicting the match of such short regeps on such short strings *should* be).

Comment: @ysth: That makes sense. I've written what I thought would be helpful. What do you think?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Where have you read about *"regexps-with-backreferences as a mathematical construct"* please? I would like to see what has been written

Comment: My bug report was closed as "Not a bug". https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=128215

Answer (score 3):

There is an even easier example of the difference between egrep and Perl:

```
grep -iE '^(([ab])|([ab]))*\2$' <<< abA
abA
perl -wE 'say for shift =~ /^(([ab])|([ab]))*\2$/i' abA
```

Interestingly, the following matches in Perl (and egrep, too):

```
grep -iE '^(([ab])|([ab]))*(\3)$' <<< abA
abA
perl -wE 'say for shift =~ /^(([ab])|([ab]))*(\3)$/i' abA
b
b
a
A
```

So, the first `a` is matched by the first iteration of `*`, `b` is matched by the second one (because `\1 eq 'b'`). At the same time, `\3 eq 'a'`, but `\4 eq 'A'`. Why is `\3 eq 'a'`? It seems to be a result of the previous iteration of the `*`, which I'd say is a bug.

**Update:** I've reported a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a go at the fourth example. (Please don't number them from zero! I people, not computer!)

```
vvXvXcvv
```

doesn't match

```
qr/ ^ (
    (v*) X
    |
    H? (v*) X
)* c \2 $ /x
```

- At the beginning of the string, perl matches the first of the two alternatives. `vvX` matches `(v*) X` so there is no need to try the alternative. That also saves capture 2 as`vv`

  That leaves `vXcvv` for the engine to match
- Again, perl uses `vX` to match `(v*) X`. It saves capture 2 as `v` and the engine goes around for another try

  That leaves `cvv`
- The only options left are another iteration of `( (v*) X | H? (v*) X )*`, or falling out of that loop into `c \2`
- The text doesn't start with `v`, `X`, or `H` so the loop ends, and the next match is `c \2`, and the regex engine matches the `c`

  Now there is only `vv` to match
- perl is now looking for a match to capture 2, which is `v`. That succeeds

  The remaining string is just `v`
- Now perl is looking for `$`, which is the end of a string, or just before a newline at the end of a string. It sees `v` and so it fails

I really hope that helps. I'm not in a hurry to explain the remaining four examples and I can't yet see why there is confusion

I haven't experimented with `egrep`, and I'm surprised that it behaves differently. Maybe it doesn't stack the captures like Perl does?

Please let me know if there's anything of further interest

Comment: but in general backtracking to a `( ... | ... )*`  does retry different alternations, and in the debug output (without the additional suggested flags; I will try to look at those later) you can see it trying all four ways of matching the alternation (left left, left right, right left, right right) but at the end it always thinks \2 is 'v'.  So I think this is just a bug

Comment: Interestingly, `/ ^ ((v*) X | H? (v*) X)* c (?: \2 | \3 ) $ /x` matches.

Comment: I understand why test 4 fails, and the same reasoning would apply to tests 6 and 8, but not the other two.  Why would it try to match the first branch again, when the next character is `H`?  Your lack of confusion confuses me. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I understand the behaviour:

```
test 3: (S3) aababcaa DOES NOT match (R1) (?^:^((a*)b|e?(a*)b)*c\2$)
```

The first part of the alternative fails here, then we use the second part.

The group 2 contains `a` so using the backreference the regex is the same as:

```
 ^(e?(a*)b)*ca$
```

That doesn't match the string `aababcaa` that has `aa` at the end.

The match is ok if you have a double `aa` in the middle: `aabaabcaa`